# sum = (1**2) + (2**2) - (3**2) + (4**2)-,...,+(n**2) program code in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

> Write a program to show the sum of `(1**2) + (2**2) - (3**2) + (4**2)-,...,+(n**2)` program code in python using "for" and "While" loop.

Although I wrote only for `+` iteration as shown below in code but `+,-,+,-` iteration is much difficult. Here is my code of `+` iteration:

```
nstart = 1
nend = 4
count = 0
Sum = 0
for i in range(nstart,nend+1):
    count+=1
    d = i**2
    Sum = Sum + d
    print(count,'**2 = ', d )

print('Sum = ', Sum)
#This program print same as [(1**2,+ 2**2,+ 3**2= 9,+,,,,+n**2 and sum of them)]
```

Comment: Maybe you can check `i % 2` and change the sign of `d` accordingly

Comment: There is a strange inconsistency in your formula: why are both the first and second term positive? Should the sign not alternate from the very start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option: use a `sign` variable and change it accordingly.

```
sum = 1**2
sign = 1 #positive
for i in range(2, n+1):
    sum += sign * (i ** 2)
    sign *= -1 #flip sign
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `% 2` check to check for odd numbers and set the sign as `+` or `-` accordingly:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, n+1):
    if i != 1 and i % 2:
        sum -= (i ** 2)
    else:
        sum += (i ** 2)
```

For `n` value 4, this outputs 12.

Comment: my problem is like this:

Comment: sum = 1+2-3+4-5 which is equal to -1 and I want to write same in for loop.

Comment: This does that and this is using `for` loop.